# JUnitCore.run() is ignoring @BeforeAll annotations

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am working in Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) with the JUnit 5 library, and it seems like none of my annotated methods are running correctly when I run a test class using JUnitCore.

For example, if I call the following class using `JUnitCore.run(TestClass.class)` :

```
public class TestClass {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        System.out.println("In TestClass.beforeAll");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("In TestClass.testMethod");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        System.out.println("In TestClass.afterAll");
    }

}
```

There is no output to System.out, and the Result object says that 1 test failed. Implying that none of these methods ran. I can use a JUnit Launcher to run the test class like so:

```
final LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
        .selectors(selectClass(TestClass.class)).build();
final Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
launcher.execute(request);
```

However, this does not give me any feedback about how many tests passed/failed, it seems to just run them. I can't find much documentation on using JUnitCore with JUnit5, is there something newer that I should be working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `JUnitCore` with JUnit 5, but instead use the platform launcher API as you did in the second part of your analysis.

`launcher#execute(.)` does not return any value, hence you need to use a listener to aggregate the results from the execution of your tests, as per the JUnit 5 documentation [7.1.2 Executing Tests](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-execution).

> There is no return value for the execute() method, but you can easily use a listener to aggregate the final results in an object of your own. For an example see the SummaryGeneratingListener.

You can for instance produce a `TestExecutionSummary` which may indeed provide you with the information you want to collect:

```
final LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = 
    LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                                   .selectors(selectClass(TestClass.class))
                                   .build();

final Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
final SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();

launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
launcher.execute(request);

TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();
long testFoundCount = summary.getTestsFoundCount();
List<Failure> failures = summary.getFailures();
...
```